# Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll missing for SSRS 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am missing this DLL reference in c:\program files\SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn.  I'm assuming that this is because I didn't install the 2005 client.  I installed all of the services for 2005, the database instance, reporting services instance, SSAS and SSIS.  I installed the 2008 client though, not the 2005 client, and 2008 database instance.

So I assume it's because I didn't install the client, but does something else give me this DLL?  Another install or a SDK or something?

Thanks.

Comment: for SQL Server 2012 its located here:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround, the report server in \ReportingServices\ReportManager\bin or ReportServer\bin has the DLL's necessary.

HTH.