# IBM.Data.DB2 FileNotFound Loading Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, db2, unity-container

I have a ASP.Net application which references an assembly with some re-usable code (common utils, data access, etc.). The assembly references `IBM.Data.DB2.dll`. However, I am not using DB2 in my application, the `IBM.Data.DB2.dll` is simply a dependency (in case an app needs to connect to DB2). Recently, i've run into the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
  at Unity.AutoRegistration.AutoRegistration.<ApplyAutoRegistration>b__5(Assembly a)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
  at Unity.AutoRegistration.AutoRegistration.ApplyAutoRegistration()
```

The only file in the entire application that contains Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces is the `IBM.Data.DB2.dll` file. I do not have any need of SQL Server or the overhead of a SQL Server installation locally much less on the server when the app is deployed. Bear in mind I am *required* to use the assembly which has the dependency on `IBM.Data.DB2.dll` and this error has not happened in the past, it seems to be recent.

I have tried binding redirects, installed Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces via Nuget all to no avail.

Would anyone know why this error is occurring and more importantly....how to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `IBM.Data.DB2.dll` references `Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces`, you will probably have to manually copy `Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll` into your `bin` folder.  Here is a post that can help you with that:

[Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll missing for SSRS 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426975/microsoft-reportingservices-interfaces-dll-missing-for-ssrs-2005)

Comment: As a test, I added Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll as a reference so it would get copied to the bin folder. That solved the problem. However, yuck....there is NO SQL server database involved nor any reporting, etc. I did not have to do this in the past two years but now all of a sudden I do?

Comment: Sounds like you came with a pretty clean workaround!  Bottom line is your IBM dll needs that other dll so you have to figure out someway to get it in there if it isn't happening automatically.